# Map MapperObject to Model- swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, objectmapper

My model is defined as

```
import ObjectMapper

class UserModel :Mappable{

    var gender: String?
    var name: String?
    var location: String?
    var email: String?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        gender <- map["gender"]
        name   <- map["name"]["title"]
        location <- map["location"]["street"]
        email <- map["email"]

    }

}
```

I have mapped json to Model using Object Mapper as

```
var results:Mappable?
```

let appUrl = "http://api.randomuser.me/?page=3&results=10"

```
func requestRandomNamesFromServer(){

        let randomPersonURl = appUrl
        Alamofire.request(.GET, randomPersonURl, parameters: nil,headers:nil).responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .Success(let data):

                print(data)
                self.results = Mapper<UserModel>().map(data)
                print(self.results)
                self.tableView.reloadData()


            case .Failure(let error):

                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")


            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is i cant figure out way to convert back in Model for displaying in TableView.I get the following errors
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are trying to map is an array of user and not just one user. 
Second
2) Mappable interface does not know anything about user properties, so you have to create an array of `UserModel`.

With this said you have to change the following lines:

`var results:Mappable?` to `var results = [UserModel]()`

`self.results = Mapper<UserModel>().map(data)` to `self.results = Mapper<UserModel>().mapArray(data["results"]!)`

Comment: is there any way i can accomplish this using map? "Mapper<UserModel>().map(data)"

Comment: i mean this way 
    let mapResults:Mappable = Mapper<UserModel>().map(data)!
                print(mapResults)
                let mappedUserResults = mapResults["data"] as! [UserModel]
                print(mappedUserResults)